# No route to host: firestore.googleapis.com

Tags: java, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, glassfish

I have a Jakarta JAX-RS REST API. From one of its endpoint method I need to retrieve some data from Firebase Firestore. This is the endpoint code.

```
@GET
@Path("/alive")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String alive() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("serviceAccountKey.json");
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    Firestore dbFirestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

    DocumentReference docRef = dbFirestore.collection("drivers").document("8QM7cdz8zOoafQSIHFsd");

    // asynchronously retrieve the document
    ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
    // block on response
    DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
    if (document.exists()) {
        return document.getData().toString();
    } else {
        return "No such document!";
    }

}
```

When I run the configuration (on a Glassfish server) and I call the api I got the error in the image. What can I do?

[image]

It seems that it doesn't work only on the server. I tried with a simple application and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to troubleshoot it better :)

Connect to the server using ssh and check connectivity to the `firestore.googleapis.com`

Try things like:

```
$ ping firestore.googleapis.com
PING firestore.googleapis.com (142.251.128.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from xxx.xxx.net (yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy): icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=23.6 ms
64 bytes from xxx.xxx.net (yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy): icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=22.7 ms
```

Then check port (in case of your pings get blocked):

```
$ apt install -y ncat # or nmap sometimes
$ ncat -zv firestore.googleapis.com 443
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 142.251.128.138:443.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.04 seconds.
```

And finally:

You are trying to connect using IPv6. Evidence from your error screenshot:
[image: evidence from your error screenshot]

Try to `ping/ncat` with IPv4 `142.251.128.138`. If it works, the problem seems to be at IPv6 stack.

In this case, you may disable IPv6 in JVM: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Or you can disable it at all on the server:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

Comment: Hi, the server is running on localhost, my machine. Pinging 142.251.128.138 from terminal works correctly. It seems to be something related to Glassfish configuration.

Comment: Since **Pinging 142.251.128.138** works (ipv4), I'm pretty sure the problem is related to the glassfish trying to connect using IPv6 (I just edited to add the evidence)

Comment: After hours of troubleshooting I finally solved. Your advice (-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true) made the error change to a SunCertPathBuilderException (this time the problem was linked to the Glassfish certificates file).